# How to change the theme of Snap Apps?

Tags: themes, gtk, snap

I am enjoying the new "snap" applications, but apps installed using this method doesn't seem to be using the system gtk theme I have set.

Some use Adwaita or worse, Raleigh.

How can I have them use the standard Ambience theme I'm using across the whole system?

Comment: Very good point. I don't think that's possible right now but certainly hope that provision will be made for some sort of customization in the future.

Answer (score 10):

The issue is being tracked here: [themes currently don't work with snaps yet](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1585332).

Comment: This is still currently a [work in progress](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/desktop-improvements-report-and-plans/3510?source_topic_id=496)

Answer (score 4):

Snap now has GTK theming support, however it requires to have the same theme installed as a snap which you have chosen on your system.

The official `gtk-common-themes` snap contains Adwaita, Adwaita-Dark, Ambiance, Arc, Arc-Dark, Arc-Darker, Breeze, Breeze-Dark, Communitheme, elementary, HighContrast, Radiance, and Yaru.

There is also `adapta-theme` and `adapta-gtk-snap` as well as `gtk2-common-themes` for GTK2 apps.

If you're not using one of these themes, I believe you're currently out of luck.

Comment: What about Qt/Kde applications?

Comment: [GTK2 Common Themes](https://snapcraft.io/gtk2-common-themes) and [GTK Common Themes](https://snapcraft.io/gtk-common-themes) are the snap themes that need to be installed.

Comment: How to use gtk-common-themes?

Answer (score 3):

I replaced the snap packages with the apt packages.

[snap list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM3ad.png)

I do the following replacement:

```
sudo snap remove gnome-calculator gnome-characters gnome-system-monitor gnome-logs
sudo apt install gnome-calculator gnome-characters gnome-system-monitor gnome-logs
```

Now the theme defined in tweak applied to these apps.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question raised.

Comment: However it's a nice work around in a pinch

Comment: I think this comment is perfectly fine, because the other replies do not address the question raised as well.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, you can force the snap to start with a theme by using the enviromental variable like this

```
GTK_THEME=Adwaita-dark /snap/bin/libreoffice.writer
```

Comment: Doesn't work for Okular, which is a Qt-application

Comment: Doesn't work if that theme is not set at desktop level.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is not available as a snap, a quick and easy fix is to automatically mount the whole themes folder on top of your snap after reboot.
So for example if you're trying to theme Shutter, you would

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And add the following line:

```
@reboot mount --bind -o nodev,ro /usr/share/themes /snap/shutter/current/usr/share/themes
```

Comment: Interesting, can you explain `nodev,ro` part?