# Some of the applications look bad in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Some of the applications in my Ubuntu 18.04 looks bad and aren't following the system-wide themes. Here is a screenshot of Sublime-text. Anyone can help me figuring what's wrong here? [image]

Comment: Sublime uses Qt and not GTK+ thus isn't reading the Gnome GTK+ themes I'm guessing. I'd suggest selecting a more appropriate Qt theme that matches your GTK+ choice.  (I'm basing this on https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libsublime8)

Comment: If you have installed these apps from Snap then it [is expected behavior](https://askubuntu.com/a/827738/66509).

Comment: @guiverc Sublime Text is a proprietary app and so not in the Ubuntu Archives. The package you're looking at there is a library from the KDE dev packaging, and not part of the proprietary text editor.

Comment: @guiverc Your hint solves the problem. I was using Ant theme. Changing that to another fixes the problem. Could you please add your comment as an answer so that I can mark it solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime uses Qt and not GTK+ thus isn't reading the Gnome GTK+ themes.

I would suggest selecting a more appropriate Qt theme that matches your GTK+ choice.

(*I'm basing this on https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libsublime8 which isn't your version/app, but I didn't see a version of sublime* for bionic*)