# Applying theme doesn't work on Chromium, Opera

Tags: themes

when i custom my Ubuntu with Gnome-Tweak, everything run correctly except some applications. Example, when i download files, Chromium's pop-up still in the default theme. The same when i switch to Use-GTK+ in Settings. How can i fix it? Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Do you use snap installation? https://askubuntu.com/questions/806668/how-to-change-the-theme-of-snap-apps

Comment: i dont remember but maybe yes, it didn't exist int appear in installed app of apt store