# Can't get system theme applied in ubuntu app store

Tags: 20.04, software-center, themes

I actually noticed that the system theme is not being applied om ubuntu app store  in ubuntu 20.04.

System Theme
[image: System Theme]

Ubuntu Software Theme
[image: Ubuntu Softwares theme]

any of the built-in theme also dont work .

so what can I do to fix this problem.

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the theme of Snap Apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806668/how-to-change-the-theme-of-snap-apps)

Comment: no bro this doesnt answer. I am asking about the ubuntu app center.

Comment: Which is a snap app... So, what exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: app is Ubuntu Softwares